# Apply textpath attribute to a link label text in Joint JS

Tags: jointjs

Can anybody please guide me on how to apply textpath attribute to a link label text in Joint JS?
I have created smooth links that follows a particular path, I want my label text to appear along that path.

Code Snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="joint.css" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
<script src="backbone.js"></script>
<script src="joint.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myholder"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
        var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
            el : $('#myholder'),
            width : 600,
            height : 200,
            model : graph,
            gridSize : 1
        });

        var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
            position : {
                x : 100,
                y : 30
            },
            size : {
                width : 100,
                height : 30
            },
            attrs : {
                rect : {
                    fill : 'blue'
                },
                text : {
                    text : 'my box',
                    fill : 'white'
                }
            }
        });

        var rect2 = rect.clone();
        rect2.translate(300);

        var link = new joint.dia.Link({
            source : {
                id : rect.id
            },
            target : {
                id : rect2.id
            },
            attrs : {
                '.connection' : {
                    'stroke' : 'lightgray',
                    'stroke-width' : 3,
                    'stroke-dasharray' : '5 2'
                },
                '.marker-source' : {
                    d : 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z',
                    fill : 'white'
                }
            },
            smooth : true,
            labels : [ {
                position : .5,
                attrs : {
                    text : {
                        text : 'LinkLabel',
                        fill : 'lightgray'
                    }
                }
            } ]
        });

        graph.addCells([ rect, rect2, link ]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried to code.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Fuzzybear, I have edited my post to include the code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a textpath attribute for a link exposed for jointjs. However the demo does use the label attribute with positions

```
labels: [
        { position: 25, attrs: { text: { text: '1..n' } }},
        { position: 0.45, attrs: { text: { text: 'multiple', fill: 'white', 'font-family': 'sans-serif' }, rect: { stroke: '#31d0c6', 'stroke-width': 20, rx: 5, ry: 5 } }},
        { position: 0.55, attrs: { text: { text: 'labels', fill: 'white', 'font-family': 'sans-serif' }, rect: { stroke: '#31d0c6', 'stroke-width': 20, rx: 5, ry: 5 } }},
        { position: -25, attrs: { text: { text: '*' } }}
    ]
```

this is for the last link in the demo
http://resources.jointjs.com/demos/links

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe someone will find it useful:

You can use the [textPath](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.5/joint.html#dia.attributes.textPath) attribute as used in the demo linked by the other answer:

It uses the smooth connector.

```js
var link8 = new joint.shapes.standard.ShadowLink({
    source: { x: 10, y: 280 },
    target: { x: 440, y: 280 },
    vertices: [{ x: 150, y: 350 }, { x: 300, y: 280 }],
    smooth: true,
    markup: [{
        tagName: 'path',
        selector: 'shadow',
        attributes: {
            'fill': 'none'
        }
    }, {
        tagName: 'path',
        selector: 'line',
        attributes: {
            'fill': 'none'
        }
    }, {
        tagName: 'text',
        selector: 'label'
    }],
    attrs: {
        line: {
            stroke: '#3c4260'
        },
        label: {
            textPath: {
                selector: 'line',
                startOffset: '50%'
            },
            textAnchor: 'middle',
            textVerticalAnchor: 'middle',
            text: 'Label Along Path',
            fill: '#f6f6f6',
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontFamily: 'fantasy'
        }
    }
});
```